# Uneditable TextView with cursor

Tags: android

I want to display some Text and fill it with my custom keyboard (grid with series of buttons). I want to indicate to a user when his entry will be inserted - a cursor. Simple EditText shows a cursor correctly but it opens system keyboard when the user touches it.

```
<EditText
    android:text="50 + 40 = 90"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp" />

unknown.setSelection(3);
```

When I add `focusable` property the cursor disappears/

```
android:focusable="false"
```

I found some similar questions where answers suggests to set `background` to null but I want to use my custom 9-patch background.

The cursor shall blink at underscore position.

[image]

Comment: your question isn't clear enough, try to clarify it more

Comment: Can you provide some UI snapshots of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I did. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Could it be possible to emulate a cursor with DynamicDrawableSpan subclass?